# How to fully disable streetview from google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I've disabled streetview controls like so:

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: myCenter,
  streetViewControl:false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("map"),
  mapOptions
);
```

Which takes the streetview control off of the map BUT if you click on a point of interest with a panoramic image / link to streetview then click that image you are again taken into streetview mode.

I want to keep my points of interest but I want to disable maps from going into streetview mode. Is this possible?

[image: streetview photo option in google maps]

## Solution

Using the answer below I added a few more items:

```
.gm-rev, .gm-sv-label{display:none;}
.gm-iw, .gm-sm, .gm-wsv{pointer-events:none;}
```

Comment: Are you ok with having POI not clickable? if so you can put polygon over POI to block them being clickable. Here is geocodezip example of that http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_rectangle-simple_RoseCanyonClear.html

Comment: @verma +1 for ingenuity but unfortunately that leaves me with the entire world of POI to have to cover up. On a localized map this may work but I'm dealing with a couple states in mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 possible options(there may be more):

1. prevent the streetView from being `visible`:

   ```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(), 'visible_changed', function(){
     if(this.getVisible()){this.setVisible(false)}
    });
   ```
2. try to make the streetview-link in the infowindow un-clickable

   ```
   .gm-sv-label{display:none;}
   .gm-wsv{pointer-events:none;}
   ```

I would suggest to use both options together, because the 2nd option may fail in the future(the classNames may change)

Comment: Using your idea I made all the content invisible and hid some items too. `.gm-rev, .gm-sv-label{display:none;}
.gm-iw, .gm-sm, .gm-wsv{pointer-events:none;}`